# Android Google Maps Move Camera

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I've been implementing Google Maps with Android. I'm using frame layout to view the map, and it works. However, I wanna use the move camera in order to focus the map to a specific location. However, i can't implement it using my code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MainMapFragement mapFragment;
private HashMap<Marker, EventInfo> eventMarkerMap;
EventInfo firstEventInfo;
Marker firstMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    mapFragment = new MainMapFragement();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.map, mapFragment);
    ft.commit();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setUpEventSpots();
}



private void setUpEventSpots() {
    // I'm going to make 2 EventInfo objects and place them on the map
    eventMarkerMap = new HashMap<Marker, EventInfo>();
    EventInfo firstEventInfo = new EventInfo(new LatLng(7.190708000000000000, 125.455340999999980000), "Right now - event", new Date(), "Party");

    Marker firstMarker= mapFragment.placeMarker(firstEventInfo);


    eventMarkerMap.put(firstMarker, firstEventInfo);


    mapFragment.getMap().setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        private final View window = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_window, null);

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            EventInfo eventInfo = eventMarkerMap.get(marker);

            String title = marker.getTitle();
            TextView txtTitle = ((TextView) window.findViewById(R.id.txtInfoWindowTitle));
            if (title != null) {
                // Spannable string allows us to edit the formatting of the text.
                SpannableString titleText = new SpannableString(title);
                titleText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, titleText.length(), 0);
                txtTitle.setText(titleText);
            } else {
                txtTitle.setText("");
            }

            TextView txtType = ((TextView) window.findViewById(R.id.txtInfoWindowEventType));
           if(eventInfo.getType() != null)
                txtType.setText(eventInfo.getType());

            return window;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            //this method is not called if getInfoWindow(Marker) does not return null
            return null;
        }
    });

}

}
```

EventInfo.java

```
public class EventInfo {

private LatLng latLong;
private String name;
private Date someDate;
private String type;

public EventInfo(LatLng latLong, String name, Date someDate, String type) {
    super();
    this.latLong = latLong;
    this.name = name;
    this.someDate = someDate;
    this.type = type;
}

public LatLng getLatLong() {
    return latLong;
}
public void setLatLong(LatLng latLong) {
    this.latLong = latLong;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Date getSomeDate() {
    return someDate;
}
public void setSomeDate(Date someDate) {
    this.someDate = someDate;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

}
```

MapFragment.java

```
public class MainMapFragement extends MapFragment {

public Marker placeMarker(EventInfo eventInfo) {
    Marker m  = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(eventInfo.getLatLong())
        .title(eventInfo.getName()));

    return m;
}
}
```

Please, how will you implement it with this code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should do it:

```
LatLng latLng = // whatever
float zoom = // whatever
mapfragment.getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// in 2021, animate camera will be a better choice :-) 
LatLng latLng = // whatever
float zoom = // whatever
mapfragment.getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
```